# this code results in a blank body

Tags: sql, response

This bit of code seems to not actually be returning anything. no matter if it tests true or false, nor the line outside the if. there is a response. but there is no body in the response. im confusd.

i can run the sql string directly on the server and get the expected response.

```
SQLcmd.CommandText = (SQLString)
SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader
    While SQLdr.READ()
        IF SQLdr(0) = "notadded" THEN
            context.Response.WRITE("notadded^") 'This is not in the body of the response
        ELSEIF
            context.Response.WRITE("added^" + SQLdr(0) + "^") 'This IS NOT IN the body OF the response
        END IF
        context.Response.WRITE(SQLcmd.CommandText) 'This is not in the body of the response
    End While
```

Comment: Doing some testing, it never entered the while loop

Comment: That would indicate that your query returned zero rows.

Comment: Or else, you're throwing an exception, but not catching it here.

Comment: figured it out. it actually was my sql statement. i did print. not select. apparently i cannot do that.

Comment: You can do that, but you shouldn't.  PRINT doesn't return any rows, it returns text messages in an alternate stream.  You need to use a different set of objects and methods to get the output from PRINT.  But again, you shouldn't, because it's intended for support messages, not for data rows.